# How to build CPP-NETLIB libraries on Windows using Code::Blocks or MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks, mingw32, cpp-netlib

Cpp-netlib's "getting started" talks about building libraries where the result should be:

```
cppnetlib-client-connections.lib
cppnetlib-server-parsers.lib
cppnetlib-uri.lib
```

It also provides CMakeLists.txt to do it, but how would I build this in Code::Blocks, or maybe a better question how would I build the libraries with MinGW ?

I am using Code::Blocks with pre-installed MinGW: `mingw32-g++ (tdm-1) 4.7.1`.

I tried to put all sources and headers into a Code::Blocks project and compile it, it has compiled successfuly and ran, but it did not produced anything and I really could not find any solution for my problem...

( cpp-netlib-0.11.0-final )

Answer (score 0):

> Just only needs to be performed once, after which the global variable
>   you've created will be available for any project.

1. Open the Settings menu and select "Global variables..."
2. Click the "New" button next to the Current variable list, specify a name like "cpp-netlib", and hit OK
3. In the "base" field of the Builtin fields section, browse for the base of your cpp-netlib installation -- the path you specified in the --prefix option of the build command
4. In the "lib" field, browse for the "cpp-netlib-0.11.1-final\libs" subfolder of your cpp-netlib installation -- it should be the path in the "base" field with "\cpp-netlib-0.11.1-final\libs" tacked on.
5. Hit the Close button to save your global variable